# calling one project into another within the same solution asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an asp.net MVC 5 project and I want to add an existing project to my solution.

I want to have a link in the first project to show the index page of the second project into a part of the one's view.

I don't know :

-how to call the second project when both have different Project URLs : http://localhost/xxxx and http://localhost/yyyy

- and if it's done I don't know how to show the index page of the second in the body section of the one's view.

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to share views between two different projects?  If so let me know and I'll post a solution.

Comment: no, it didn't want to share views between projects , i resolved my problem by using areas.. thank you